# Endpoint of a fillet when radius and one endpoint is known

Tags: math, triangular

I'm creating a fillet between two lines, one is vertical and other is at an angle theta, I need to find the coordinates for the endpoint [one of them is cos(theta)*radius]. How would I go about doing that?

[Edited the question with this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kocye.jpg)

Comment: A diagram would be very helpful. Are you looking for both coordinates of one endpoint, or the coordinates of one given the coordinates of the other? Is `radius` the radius of the fillet, or the distance from one of the tangent points (i.e. an endpoint of the fillet) to the intersection of the two lines?

Comment: @beta I have added the diagram as suggested. radius is the radius of the fillet. Thank you.

Comment: I never would have guessed that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Since I don't have a good way to make diagrams, I'll have to do this in words.)

Take a circle of radius r, centered on the origin. A line, making an angle θ with the horizontal, is tangent to the circle in the (x<0, y>0) quadrant. The coordinates of the tangent point are (-r sin(θ), r cos(θ)). Drop a verttical from the tangent point, and it will intersect the x-axis at (-r sin(θ), 0).

The distance from that intersection to the leftmost point of the circle is

```
d = -r sin(θ) - (-r) = r(1 - sin(θ))
```